# Send post variable in AJAX to PHP file for varaible

Tags: javascript, php

What should happen:

- When button clicked, it calls report.php and sends "main" as type
- Type "main" is picked up in report.php and used as $typename
- $data varaible is populated with the contents of main.json

What does happen:

```
>     [25-Sep-2018 13:56:56] WARNING: [pool www] child 11 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in
> /var/www/html/report.php on line 27"
>     [25-Sep-2018 13:56:56] WARNING: [pool www] child 11 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(.json):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/www/html/report.php on line 28"
>     2018/09/25 13:57:00 [error] 8#8: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in
> /var/www/html/report.php on line 27
```

**index.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'report.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data: ({type: main}),
            success: function(result){
                $("#output").html(result);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

**report.php**

```
$typename = $_POST['type'];
echo $typename;
$data = file_get_contents("$typename.json");
```

**main.json**

```
{
    "reportDescription":{ <....>
}
```

Comment: Where is the javascript variable `main` defined? Because I don't see it anywhere, meaning you haven't showed us all the code, or I found your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Second @GrumpyCrouton, also don't see you feeding the resulting JSON back to the client anywhere in your PHP code.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I just want it to have the value main (not a variable etc). I'm a bit new, are you saying it should be ```data: ({type: 'main'}),```

Comment: The parens are unnecessary, and yes.

Comment: @Jimmy So it should be the string `"main"`? So yes, it should be `data: ({type: 'main'}),` or `data: ({type: "main"}),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to send an undefined variable `main` to your php file. This variable doesn't exist, so you get an error. Strings must be wrapped with single or double quotes.

You should change `data: ({type: main}),` to

```
data: {type: 'main'},
```

(The perenthesis are not needed)

To send the string to your PHP file.

Now in your PHP file, you need to output `$data`.

```
$typename = $_POST['type'];
echo $typename;
$data = file_get_contents("$typename.json");
echo $data;
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the help. Will mark as answer in 5

Comment: @Jimmy Glad I could help.

Comment: Note that the parens are unnecessary.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Sorry to be a pain but I tested it and even then I get the same error with this output ```[25-Sep-2018 14:16:04] WARNING: [pool www] child 11 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /var/www/html/report.php on line 28"```

Comment: @Jimmy On the PHP before anything else, can you do `print_r($_POST)` and tell me what the output is?

Comment: `$data = file_get_contents("{$typename}.json");` to get the value rather than the variable id as a string

Comment: @Parody It's between double quotes, so the current code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `data: {type: 'main'},` as [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52500237/2739274).

But the php code in that answer could be improved. This code could lead to security issues, particularly to a [Server Side Request Forgery](http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/server-side-request-forgery-vulnerability/). You need to set a clear boundary between the user supplied data and your application code, you need to validate the code to avoid some evil uses of `file_get_contents`:

- One can **request a random website** by http or use another protocol like **ssh** to connect to other server reachable from your web server
- Someone can **scan your directories** and **read operating system files**

So, beware what you do with user input, you need to validate it. I would use the following code.

```
  // strip all slashes and directories, use only the filename
  $typename = basename($_POST['type']);
  $filename = __DIR__.'/'.basename($_POST['type']).".json";

  if (!file_exist($filename)){
     echo "ERROR";
  }
  // do not output anything till validated
  // echo $typename;
  // use a header to tell the user that this is a json file
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $data = file_get_contents($filename);
  echo $data;
```